# Computing concave hull from points using PostGIS and display in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, convex-hull

I'd like to create a boundary of a set of point using `ST_ConcaveHull` function in PostGIS

My query works fine and I can see the polygon through the geometry viewer embedded in the pgadmin.

```sql
CREATE TABLE boundary AS
SELECT row_number() OVER () As id,  ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(p.geom), 0.99) As geom
FROM mypoints p;
```

However, when I try to load the table in QGIS, it gives me an error saying `the layer is invalid`.

I try to explicitly define the geometry type as polygon, but this error `Geometry type (GeometryCollection) does not match column type (Polygon)`

```sql
CREATE TABLE boundary AS
SELECT row_number() OVER () As id,  ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(p.geom), 0.99)::geometry(POLYGON,4326) As geom
FROM mypoints p;
```

How do I refine my query to create a table that can be recognised by QGIS?

Comment: Using PostGIS 3 with PostgreSQL 12  on Ubuntu 20.04 your first query works. I got a Polygon layer in the same EPSG as the source table.

Comment: But are you able to open the table in QGIS @Zoltan?

Comment: There is only ST_Point in the mypoints table @BERA

Comment: @Scorpioooooon21, yes I can open it from QGIS. Of course I use one of my point tables to generate concave-hull.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also replace ST_Collect by ST_Union, though the result in the form of a convex hull may change a bit :-)...

Comment: Title talks about convex hull but the SQL is using concave hull. Please edit one or another.

Comment: @user30184 updated the title. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks, @CyrilMikhalchenko but the ST_Union function also return a Geometrycollection. I think my problem here is how to extract Polygons from Geometrycollection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The convex hull algorithm is somewhat delicate, and `ST_ConvexHull` makes no effort to preserve and validate topology and geometry - it is possible that parts of the constructed hull collapses into lower-dimensional geometries during the process.

You'd need to dump the `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`, and filter for a specifc geometry type:

```
CREATE TABLE boundary AS
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
         ST_SetSRID(dmp.geom, 4326)::GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326) AS geom
  FROM   (
    SELECT ST_Collect(geom) AS geom
    FROM   mypoints
  ) AS q, LATERAL ST_Dump(ST_ConcaveHull(geom, 0.99)) AS dmp
  WHERE  GeometryType(dmp.geom) = 'POLYGON'
;
```

---

It may be a good idea to check on, and visualize what is happening; use `ST_AsText` to see what gets returned, then load each geometry type as individual layer into QGIS for inspection:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
       ST_AsText(dmp.geom, 4326) AS wkt_geom
FROM   (
  SELECT ST_Collect(geom) AS geom
  FROM   mypoints
) AS q, LATERAL ST_Dump(ST_ConcaveHull(geom, 0.99)) AS dmp
-- WHERE  GeometryType(dmp.geom) = '<type>'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @geozelot works perfectly.

I also manage to extract polygon by using `ST_CollectionExtract`.
Below is my revised query and the table is now accessible from QGIS too.

```sql
CREATE TABLE boundary AS
SELECT row_number() OVER () As id, ST_CollectionExtract(ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(p.geom), 0.99),3) As geom
FROM mypoints p;
```